# Wordpress admin area too many redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In order to manage my WordPress site with Git, I've added WordPress as a submodule in my site's root. Particularly I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2012/04/09/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/) to do so

My site's root directory looks as follows:

```
    .git
    .gitmodules
    .htaccess
    index.php
    wordpress
    wp-config.php
    wp-content
```

With this structure, my site's frontend works as expected without issue. However I cannot access my site's admin area due to too many redirects on `mydomain.com/wp-admin`

I can't seem to figure this one out. My `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

I have made the necessary changes to index.php and wp-config.php which allow WordPress to exist in a subdirectory, but I can't figure out where the redirect loop on the wp-admin area is occurring.

Comment: wouldn't it be /wordpress/wp-admin/ ?

Comment: /wordpress/wp-admin gives me a 404. I can get to /wordpress/wp-login.php, however when trying to login in, the login form submits to /wp-login.php and I get too many redirects. I've set both the 'siteurl' option in wp_options and WP_SITEURL in config.php to 'my domain.com/wordpress' but still no luck.

Comment: I was able to sort out my own issue. Turns out (like always) it was a simple solution. I was using a drop-in (wp-content/db.php) as outlined here http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress, for the purpose of detecting my environment. The drop-in was preventing WordPress from seeing that the core was installed in a subdirectory, namely /wordpress. Not sure if any one will have a similar issue as specific as mine, but perhaps this will help someone down the road.